# Black-and-White Sci-Fi Movie with Cone-shaped Aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I really don't know much about this movie anymore, since I've seen it only once as a child more than 30 years ago in the early 80's.

It was black-and-white, probably from the 50's or 60's and although I was really fascinated and considered it as one of the best movies ever made it was probably a B-Movie of some kind.

Fragments of the story: Aliens are visiting Earth, whether for invasion or a friendly visit I can't remember. People are frightened and try to fight the aliens. Near the end, the Aliens are shown as large vaguely cone-shaped creatures of about 3 meters in height: one large cone with the tip at the bottom and one smaller cone or a dome at the top/head. The aliens moved by hovering over the ground.

Me and my siblings watched a lot of sci-fi movies like this during one year (in fact, every time grandma was babysitting). The movie was probably part of a series of the respective German TV station (WDR?) and might have something in common with the movie *The Incredible Shrinking Man* which I remember clearly from such an occasion.

---

Viewed *It Came From Outer Space* on Prime. Really enjoyed it and realised how much Jack Arnold shaped my sci-fi preferences but it is really not the film I am looking for.

Comment: Found the film "It Came from Outer Space" by the same regisserur Jack Arnold, but I don't really recognize the alien. On the other hand, the gliding/hovering is there. Might be, maybe it was too long ago.

Comment: This is a long shot, but check out pictures at imdb of the alien from It Conquered the World (a 1956 B&W Sci-Fi film directed by Roger Corman).  That alien is definitely shaped like a cone (4-5 feet tall) with two arms and a very mean looking face.  The alien doesn't hover, but it does send out bat-like flying creatures that attack people and they could be the "hovering" creatures you remember.

Comment: @tim thank you for your hint, but "It Conquered the World" is definitely not the film I remeber. The aliens look interesting though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [*It Conquered the World*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049370/) (1956). It's available on YouTube.

> A well meaning scientist guides an alien monster to Earth from Venus, so that he can rid mankind of feelings and emotions - but only death and sorrow results.

According to one of the writers:

> **CG:** Yeah, that’s the one [actress] Beverly Garland kicked over and said, “That conquered the world?!” I called it Denny Dimwit and somebody else called it an ice-cream cone.
>
> [source](http://sensesofcinema.com/2005/conversations-with-filmmakers/charles_b_griffith/)

Comment: Please add details as to how this matches.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP said in a now-deleted comment that this is not it. Good guess, though!